# Countdown with restart button just adds the new countdown over the old one making it "flicker"

Tags: javascript, countdown

Right now I don't have the whole code I used, but I think this should be the part that causes it:

```
function init() {
    window.addEventListener('load', startCountdown);

    document.getElementById('reset').addEventListener("click", startCountdown);
}


function startCountdown() {
    new countdown(1800, 'cd'); // "1800" = 30 Minuten
}
```

Is there a way to add another function that will remove the old countdown?

Comment: Please click the `<>` snippet editor and create a [mcve] - we cannot guess without seeing your code

Comment: What is the `countdown` function? From some library?